# Get all text between <br> tag

Tags: java, xml

A real complex situation. At least looks like that to me.
What I got? A list of `org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl` which I can cast to w3c Node. No problem. So basically I will have `List<Node>`.

But my task is to extract all text between `<br>` or `<br/>` tag. It will be more clear when you see example of xml:

```
<Text>
    <FONT color="blue">
        <U>fhdgfhdfghdfghdfg</U>
    </FONT>
    <FONT color="blue">
        <STRONG>      dsfsfdfsghdfh:</STRONG>
    </FONT>
    <FONT color="blue"/>
    <FONT color="blue">
        <STRONG> 32423</STRONG>
    </FONT>
    <FONT color="blue">
        <STRONG>-2013<br/>
        </STRONG>
    </FONT>
    <STRONG>- dkjhgkjsdhgf</STRONG> sdafas asd fasdf 17-05-12<br/>- fgdhdfh gsdfg fdg 8-400 <br/>
    <STRONG>- </STRONG>
    <STRONG>dfdfgsdf </STRONG> dfgsdfgsdfgsdg.......................................<br/>- 
    <STRONG>sdfasdfasfdas </STRONG>asdfasasddfsdgdfsgsdf.......<br/>
</Text>
```

For output I have to create strings, which will be as much as there are 'br' tags. Something like this will be output of this xml:

string 1: fhdgfhdfghdfghdfg      dsfsfdfsghdfh: 32423-2013

string 2: - dkjhgkjsdhgf sdafas asd fasdf 17-05-12

string 3: - fgdhdfh gsdfg fdg 8-400

string 4: - dfdfgsdf  dfgsdfgsdfgsdg.......................................

string 5: - sdfasdfasfdas asdfasasddfsdgdfsgsdf.......

Any advice on how to approach to this?

Comment: did you try any html parsing library - say jsoup?

Comment: You don't actually have `<br>` open tags in your example, And <br> does not support opening tags